# JOOQ handling nested list UPSERT

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

Using the documentation [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.13/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/) I know I can use `onDuplicateKeyUpdate` to handle an UPSERT. But, how can I match values when inserting a list of list values? I'm using Postgres as the actual implementation here.

Suppose the following Java taking in a nested List, then starting a JOOQ query.

```java
List<List<String>> values = List.of(List.of("1", "2", "3"), List.of("4", "5", "6"));

dsl.insertInto(TABLE)
        .values(values)
        .onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
```

Next I would have to call `set()` in the fluent call. However, with this being a nested list I cannot access each item here.

For example, suppose the database contains this row already:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|   1  |   0  |   0  |
+------+------+------+
```

With Col1 being the primary key, I'd expect the above code to do an UPSERT and try to insert, but then fail on the first row. Updating `col2` & `col3` respectively. Then doing a normal insert for the second. Becoming:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|   1  |   2  |   3  |
+------+------+------+
|   4  |   5  |   6  |
+------+------+------+
```

As SQL this would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO table(col1, col2 col3)
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
ON CONFLICT (col1)
DO UPDATE SET
col1 = excluded.col1,
col2 = excluded.col2,
col3 = excluded.col3
```

Is there a good way to handle this in JOOQ? Or should I just go with raw SQL and bind in values instead?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pending feature request here for dynamic multi values insert statements: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6604

It includes some workaround discussions. It's possible to do today, just not convenient. Notice, if you're targeting PostgreSQL only, I recommend you use jOOQ's `ON CONFLICT` support